# The "Shadow" option is not available in "Show Layer Properties" (Blender 3.5)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, render-passes, viewlayers

When I turn on Cycles to render, I have no "Shadows" option in "Show Layer Properties" (*Passes > Light > Other > ...*), but in the video tutorial everything works perfectly.

What could be the problem?

[image: Example]  [image]

Comment: This option has been removed: [Reference/Release Notes/3.5/Cycles - Blender Developer Wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.5/Cycles): "*The shadow render pass was removed, as its design was incompatible with the light tree. In many case shadow catcher passes can be used instead.*"

Comment: @quellenform it would be good as a standalone answer I think, this question will no doubt show up again in the future

Comment: @Gorgious Yes, you are probably right. I will gladly comply with this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just to be able to mark this question as "solved", here is a short answer from the comments...

This option has been removed, as can be read in the [release notes of version 3.5](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.5/Cycles):

*"The shadow render pass was removed, as its design was incompatible with the light tree. In many case shadow catcher passes can be used instead ([0731d78d](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/0731d78d))."*