# shadows removed in layers

Tags: shadows

[image][The "Shadow" option is not available in "Show Layer Properties" (Blender 3.5)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/290688/the-shadow-option-is-not-available-in-show-layer-properties-blender-3-5) was a link to this question however i want to be able to manipulate the shadows in compositing tab i am following a guide on youtube and since the shadow option was removed im stumped on what to do, i am currently making my own caustics with lights and they arent as visible so what he did was tick the shadow option and then go to composting to edit them ( i cant send his video as it was his patreon and i would not want to ruin his hustle and send out videos he wants to be paid for.)